# KiCAD - Moving and rotating components with wires connected

Tags: kicad

I'm a major major noob to KiCAD and having done a couple of tuts in Eagle, I do like the separation of footprints from the schema.

But one thing that took me by surprise is that the wire connections don't stay connected or become weird angled if I move or rotate the components.

I know I can move the components with `G` or right-clicking and selecting `Drag` to retain the wiring, but it no longer stays at right angles and starts going in every direction. Is there any way to avoid that?

Secondly, is there any way to rotate the component while maintaining the wire connections?

Comment: When I "grab" and "move", the wires stay connected, but when I "grab" and "rotate" the wire connections are lost... Seems like a bug for me

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can rotate components while keeping wires connected by clicking g for grab, then clicking r for rotate. It's very convenient.

But like you noted, it doesn't keep any right angles you chose, and instead connects them with the shortest route from the closest break-point in the wire. By breakpoint I mean some point that isn't a straight line.

I don't know if there's a way to force the wires to behave how you ask. There might be a setting to forbid any angled lines in the schematic. And then that setting might behave how you want when you rotate. But you can imagine it's hard to keep wires "neat" when you go about rotating them from the initial configuration. It would require the program to dynamically organize the wires itself.

Comment: Yea - I guess there isn't a way at the moment. Thanks!